# Is it possible to find data that have duplicate values in one column but not others using bash?

Tags: bash, sorting, multiple-columns, uniq

I have a file with multiple columns and rows. I would like to take the data and find rows where there are duplicates of the value in column 4 and then print those rows to a new file.

My data file looks like this:

```
 RR2.out    -1752.142111    -1099486.696073  0.000000
 SS2.out    -1752.142111    -1099486.696073  0.000000
 RR1.out    -1752.141887    -1099486.555511  0.140562
 SS1.out    -1752.141887    -1099486.555511  0.140562
 RR4.out    -1752.140564    -1099485.725315  0.970758
 SS4.out    -1752.140564    -1099485.725315  0.970758
 RR3.out    -1752.140319    -1099485.571575  1.124498
 SS3.out    -1752.140319    -1099485.571575  1.124498
 SS5.out    -1752.138532    -1099484.450215  2.245858
 RR6.out    -1752.138493    -1099484.425742  2.270331
 SS6.out    -1752.138493    -1099484.425742  2.270331
 file Gibbs kcal rel
 file Gibbs kcal rel
```

If I just use uniq -d I only get

```
file Gibbs kcal rel
file Gibbs kcal rel
```

because they are the only two lines that match completely. What I want to know is if there is a way to find all rows that have duplicate values in column 4, not always an entire match.

I then use awk and read to read in the file names in column 1, so ideally I wouldn't have to transfer the data to another file and then back in, as I have found that this can cause errors related to the reading of the file names.

In this example, I should get the following file as an output:

```
 RR2.out    -1752.142111    -1099486.696073  0.000000
 SS2.out    -1752.142111    -1099486.696073  0.000000
 RR1.out    -1752.141887    -1099486.555511  0.140562
 SS1.out    -1752.141887    -1099486.555511  0.140562
 RR4.out    -1752.140564    -1099485.725315  0.970758
 SS4.out    -1752.140564    -1099485.725315  0.970758
 RR3.out    -1752.140319    -1099485.571575  1.124498
 SS3.out    -1752.140319    -1099485.571575  1.124498
 RR6.out    -1752.138493    -1099484.425742  2.270331
 SS6.out    -1752.138493    -1099484.425742  2.270331
 file Gibbs kcal rel
 file Gibbs kcal rel
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`uniq` has the `-f`/`--skip-fields` option to ignore the first n fields of each line.

```
uniq -D -f3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of code that can accomplish what you are looking for:

```
awk ' BEGIN { OLD4 = "No match" }
$4 == OLD4 { print LAST ; print  } 
{ OLD4 = $4 ; LAST = $0  }  '
```

So here's how you might run it:

```
awk ' BEGIN { OLD4 = "No match" }
$4 == OLD4 { print LAST ; print  } 
{ OLD4 = $4 ; LAST = $0  }  '   inputfile
```

Where inputfile looks like this:

```
RR2.out    -1752.142111    -1099486.696073  0.000000
 SS2.out    -1752.142111    -1099486.696073  0.000000
 RR1.out    -1752.141887    -1099486.555511  0.140562
 SS1.out    -1752.141887    -1099486.555511  0.140562
 RR4.out    -1752.140564    -1099485.725315  0.970758
 SS4.out    -1752.140564    -1099485.725315  0.970758
 RR3.out    -1752.140319    -1099485.571575  1.124498
 SS3.out    -1752.140319    -1099485.571575  1.124498
 SS5.out    -1752.138532    -1099484.450215  2.245858
 RR6.out    -1752.138493    -1099484.425742  2.270331
 SS6.out    -1752.138493    -1099484.425742  2.270331
 file Gibbs kcal rel
 file Gibbs kcal rel
```

There's an issue with this program, it assumes column 4 is sorted.  If this is indeed the case, you can use the code unmodified.  Otherwise, it may be worth while to sort the input by column 4 before passing it to awk.

To correct the sorting issue, you may want to sort the file as you input it to awk.  This will change the order of the output, so more coding may be required.

Here's the awk script with a sort of the input:

```
awk ' BEGIN { OLD4 = "No match" }
$4 == OLD4 { print LAST ; print  } 
{ OLD4 = $4 ; LAST = $0  }  '   <( sort -k4,4 inputfile )
```

Alternatively:

```
sort -k4,4 inputfile | awk ' BEGIN { OLD4 = "No match" }
$4 == OLD4 { print LAST ; print  } 
{ OLD4 = $4 ; LAST = $0  }  '
```